# unique group structure on elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties, group-schemes

Let $C$ be a curve of genus $1$ over a field $k$ with a $k$-rational point $O$, then by the theory of elliptic curve, there is a group structure $(C(k),+)$ on $C$ given by geometric construction or induced by the group structure of Pic$^0(C)$, and these two constructions give the same group structure with $O$ as the zero element.

Then I want to know if there exists another group structure $(C(k),\oplus)$ on $C$ with $O$ as the zero element again, but now there exists some pair $P,Q\in C(k)$ such that $P+Q\neq P\oplus Q$.

Edit: After reading Servaes's answer to this question, I am more concerned  with a construction compatible with complex topology or Zariski topology.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you want your $\oplus$ to be a morphism of varieties too??

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Yes. Without topology, it is less interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course; let $\sigma$ be any permutation of $C(k)$ that fixes $O$. Then the operation
$$\oplus:\ C(k)\times C(k)\ \longrightarrow\ C(k):\ (x,y)\ \longmapsto\ \sigma^{-1}(\sigma(x)+\sigma(y)),$$
defines a group structure on $C(k)$ with $O$ as its identity element. It is not hard to see that if $|C(k)|>3$ then there exists a permutation $\sigma$ so that the two operations $\oplus$ and $+$ are distinct.

Comment: This is a correct answer to the question. I'd just point out that it doesn't answer the more pertinent question of whether $E/k$ can be equipped with another structure as a *group variety*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Moreover, I wonder if we assume that the group operation $C(k)\times C(k)\ \longrightarrow\ C(k)$ is continuous in the Zariski topology or when $k$ is the complex field $\mathbb{C}$, we assume that the group operation is holomorphic, then does there exist such a group structure different from the group structure given by Pic$^{0}(k)$?

Comment: @Mummytheturkey   I am more concerned about if there exists a construction compatible with topology, complex topology or Zariski topology.

Answer (score 1):

The group structure on any abelian variety is unique up to zero section. See Remark 1.3 in [Milne's notes on abelian varieties](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf).

Comment: Yes, the identity map is a regular bijective map, by Milne this is a group homomorphism, so the group structure is really the same. Thanks!